# How to search in SQLite Database by using String variable not Integer?

Tags: android, sqlite

Part of my application is to bring user account information from dynamic database. When a user entered his username and password, I will search for username in the database and bring all data related to his username. I am using getTwitterAccount for search and My primary key is String "TW_USERNAME". Here it's part of database code:

```
public String[] getTwitterAccount(String username) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_1, null, TW_USERNAME + "=" + username, null, null, null, null, null);


    if ((cursor.getCount() == 0) || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] account = new String[3]; 
    account[0] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TW_USERNAME));
    account[1] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TW_AUTH_KEY));
    account[2] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TW_AUTH_SECRET_KEY));

    return account;
}
```

I got error in the query. I searched for this problem and they said "Primary key should be integer "_id". Is there anyway to search in the database by using String not Integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this: TW_USERNAME + "= '" + username +"'" Your input parameter should be in single quotes, if it is String.

Comment: my input is (username) which entered by the user, and I want to compare it with TW_USERNAME column to bring correct raw. I don't understand what are trying to do!

Comment: What I am saying is your username (what ever user inputs) should be in single quotes while querying sqldatabase.  Try it, it will work according to your need. Here is SO link, it seems someone had similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564215/problem-with-sql-query-android-where-clause